# Scala Pattern-matching on a constructor with parameters, but also reusing the object

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am using a match statement a want to match on a particular constructor, while also use the object on the right side of case. e.g., in following example I want to use the object of `MyClass` on the right side, but I don't know how to refer to it.

```
match x {
 case MyClass(a1)::remainingList => ?
 case ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x match {
  case (head @ MyClass(s)) :: tail => ...
  case Nil => ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the match to a value for reference later, as in

```
case f: Foo => foo.bar
```

Alternatively, if what you are matching is a case class you can unpack it into a tuple like:

```
case (foo, bar) => foo + bar
```

If you only want to match the head to a specific class you can pass the head into the match statement instead of the whole list

```
myList.head match {
  case f: Foo => f.bar
}
```

Comment: @Kocko I am matching a list. And I want to match its head to a specific class.

Comment: It is difficult without knowing your specific use case but if you are only working with the head of the list I would lean towards matching the head explicitly as in my third example.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible only with list.head

```
  case class MyClass(s: String)

  val seq = Seq(MyClass("a"), MyClass("b"))

  seq match {
    case my @ MyClass(s) :: xs => println(my.head)
  }
```

Comment: `my` is useless here. You can call simply `seq.head`

Comment: if you have Seq(MyClass("a"), "b") (Seq[Any]) it's still useful if you need to check types